# Trying to animate Components inside a ternary operator

Tags: javascript, react-native, animation

I am trying to make a screen, which opens the camera if there is no media already saved in the state. It should also be possible to open the camera(and it should also have an animation) on the other screen. Here's my current code:

```
const Screen = () => {
  const media = useSelector((state) => state.add.media);
  const [show, setShow] = useState(true);

  return media.length === 0 ? (
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <Transition
        items={show}
        from={{ opacity: 0 }}
        enter={{ opacity: 1 }}
        leave={{ opacity: 0 }}
      >
        {(show) =>
          show &&
          ((props) => {
            return <Camera onLeave={() => setShow(false)} />;
          })
        }
      </Transition>
    </View>
  ) : (
    <View>
      <Typography>Media not empty</Typography>
      <TouchableOpacity>Should open camera(not implemented yet)</TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
}
```

I am currently using `Transition` from `react-spring`, but it doesn't work. I tried wrapping the entire component inside the `Transition` but also nothing. I also tried `react-native-pose` and couldn't get it to work either. Any help? Thanks..

Comment: It would improve your question if you could be more specific than " it doesn't work". (Eg, what unexpected behavior do you see from the posted code?)

Comment: @Cat sorry, I meant there is simply no animation. The component mounts/unmounts as it should, but it just appears, without the opacity change/animation. I also wanted to try creating an animation where the camera 'slides out' of the view by changing its y position, but that also did nothing.